# How to Calculating discount price from discount percentage

Tags: php, json, laravel

I getting the discount percentage of the offer product but I need to display the amount of that percentage. i.e actual value is 400 discount% is 37.50 need to print discount amount is 150 in the blade file. but now it's print 0

This is My Controller

```
$perc = 0;
 $discountprice=0;
if ($value->IsOfferItem) {
    $perc = round(100 - (($value->SellingPrice / $value->ActualPrice) * 100), 2);
    $discountprice = (($value->ActualPrice * $perc)/100);
}
$data['data']['products'][] = [
    'price'            => $value->SellingPrice,
    'oldprice'         => $value->ActualPrice,
    'discountprice'=>$discountprice,
    'offperc'          => $perc . "%",
];

$data['data']['cartlist']['data'][]=[

'offperc'              =>number_format((float)$value->Discount, 2, '.', '')."%",
 'discountprice'        => number_format($discountprice, 2,'.', ''),
```

My Blade file

```
    @foreach ($data['cartlist']['data'] as $list) 
@if ($list['IsOfferItem'])
    {{ $list['discountprice'] }}
@endif
    

@endforeach
```

Comment: So what is the problem here? Is the rendering not working?

Comment: @ Kingalione  how to display that amount

Comment: @ Kingalione  how to display that amount

Comment: Andy Song  actually I passed that but out showing is zero

Comment: how hard is it for you to update your question properly and explain better rather than put all the code in the comment

Comment: Andy Song I updated the code